# ANTLR4 Parser C# Project Simple Arithmetics

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I know there are tutorials for such but none of them have been helpful so far, googled for the past like 5 hours but still no success. Am trying to build a simple arithmetics calculator and I found a perfect language for online, I have built using the jar file to generate project files for c# but am stuck there.
Here is the grammer

```
grammar testGrammer;

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

 compileUnit
    :   expression + EOF
    ;

expression
   : multiplyingExpression ((PLUS | MINUS) multiplyingExpression)*
   ;

multiplyingExpression
   : powExpression ((TIMES | DIV) powExpression)*
   ;

powExpression
   : atom (POW atom)*
   ;

atom
   : scientific
   | variable
   | LPAREN expression RPAREN
   | func
   ;

scientific
   : number (E number)?
   ;

func
   : funcname LPAREN expression RPAREN
   ;

funcname
   : COS
   | TAN
   | SIN
   | ACOS
   | ATAN
   | ASIN
   | LOG
   | LN
   ;

number
   : MINUS? DIGIT + (POINT DIGIT +)?
   ;

variable
   : MINUS? LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*
   ;

COS
   : 'cos'
   ;

SIN
   : 'sin'
   ;

TAN
   : 'tan'
   ;

ACOS
   : 'acos'
   ;

ASIN
   : 'asin'
   ;

ATAN
   : 'atan'
   ;

LN
   : 'ln'
   ;

LOG
   : 'log'
   ;

LPAREN
   : '('
   ;

RPAREN
   : ')'
   ;

PLUS
   : '+'
   ;

MINUS
   : '-'
   ;

TIMES
   : '*'
   ;

DIV
   : '/'
   ;

POINT
   : '.'
   ;

E
   : 'e' | 'E'
   ;

POW
   : '^'
   ;

LETTER
   : ('a' .. 'z') | ('A' .. 'Z')
   ;

DIGIT
   : ('0' .. '9')
   ;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

WS
    :[ \r\n\t] + -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
```

and here is its properties

[image: testGrammer.g4 properties]

The following are the project files

[image: File structure]

I know there should be some visitor class but am seriously stuck. I don't know how to proceed from here and to be honest it is my first time working with ANTLR or any other language parsers. 
Here is what I have so far and as you can see it's giving me a bunch of errors.

[image: class code]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Antlr4.Runtime;
using Antlr4.Runtime.Tree;


namespace ExpressionParser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String input = "3625";
            ICharStream stream = CharStreams.fromString(input);
            ITokenSource lexer = new testGrammerLexer(stream);
            ITokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            testGrammerParser parser = new testGrammerParser(tokens);
            parser.buildParseTrees = true;
            IParseTree tree = parser.StartRule();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help please, thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors do you get? A red underline is not enough for an error message ;)

Comment: Okay I copied the example from this [page](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/csharp-target.md) and the lexer and parser classes are empty, even if I create a constructor which takes in that one argument (in both lexer and parser classes) I still wouldn't know how to deal with the parsed variable, plus I am missing a visitor class and a visitorbase classes @Sylence

Comment: Have you opened the generated .cs files (the lexer and the parser)? Are they empty? If they are generated without problems they must have those constructors. Have you installed the Antlr Nuget package in your project? Also, the method `parser.StartRule()` not exists in your project, because you dont have a `StartRule` rule in your grammar, I think you should use `parser.compileUnit();` in your case.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions they pretty much solved almost all the problems, but I still have one left, this line: `ICharStream stream = CharStreams.fromString(input)` still gives me an error `the name charstreams does not exist in the current context` and am still searching for a fix for that, can you help me out there too please @AlejandroPérezFals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to use CharStream. Use this:

```
AntlrInputStream input = new AntlrInputStream("3625");
            ITokenSource lexer = new testGrammerLexer(input);
            ITokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            testGrammerParser parser = new testGrammerParser (tokens);
            IParseTree tree = parser.compileUnit();
```

If you want to implement a Listener use this:

```
YourListener expressionWalker = new YourListener();

        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker(); //get the walker
        walker.Walk(tablesWalker, tree);
```

You have to create YourListener:

```
public class TablesWalker : testGrammerBaseListener
    {
    //override methods to evaluate expression
}
```

Comment: thanks, i used this `ITokenSource lexer = new testGrammerLexer(new AntlrInputStream(input));` so moving on to listeners now

Comment: Please, mark the answer as correct and vote for it, Thanks!!

Comment: actually upto there it was really helpful, thanks, but using visitor instead